# How to check if the date is within a specifed date range

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have a date range fixed from **30th** of current month to **10th** of next month.

I am using PHP with MySQL. In PHP I hardcode the array:

```
$dates = array(30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

therefore before the connection to the database been made, I've already filtered if the date falls on any of this range, if yes, allowed, if no, disallowed.

However, in MySQL what database table design and query should I use for following **requirements**:

1. User initiate an action to insert data, if no record between the above date range, system allow the insert else disallow.
2. User may at any point of time press the button to perform the action therefore I need to check if any record exist at that moment (*perhaps the checking is the hardest part*).

The possible scenarios are:

1. Given current date is 31-DEC-2016 (valid because in the date range), user try to insert the data and no data in database, therefore successfully insert.
2. The next day, 01-DEC-2016 user try to insert again but system detected a record already existed in the date range of the current date falls in (01-DEC-2016 falls in the range of 31-DEC-2016 ~ 10-JAN-2017) *how to query this scenario?*

Comment: make the date field unique

Comment: `what database table design and query should I use for following requirements` this doesn't belong here at SO. You can ask at  dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: An INSERT... SELECT type query will suffice. For further help see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you have to do it in MySQL only? What about checking in PHP? What about if it's Jan 15? Then user should insert one day later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `monthly` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `period` char(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `period` (`period`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

where action_date will be your actual date in MySQL date format (i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`), and period will be a `YYYYMM` format identifier that will have the same value for each day in your defined date range.

Use this expression to calculate the period value for a given date:

```
select (
    case 
        when (day('2016-01-30') mod 30) > 10 then null 
        when (day('2016-01-30') div 30) = 1 then concat(year('2016-01-30'), lpad(month('2016-01-30'), 2, 0)) 
        else concat(year('2016-01-30' - interval 1 month), lpad(month('2016-01-30' - interval 1 month), 2, 0)) 
    end) 
as period;
```

Using '2016-12-30' in the above will yield '201612', using '2017-01-07' will also yield '201612', using '2017-01-12' will yield null. Since the period column is `unique` and `not null`,  you won't be able to insert values that fall out of your defined range, and you'll be able to insert only one value per your range.

Use the following statement to insert new values into the table (replacing the date values of course with your actual date):

```
insert into monthly (action_date, period) 
values (
    '2017-01-30',
    case 
        when (day('2017-01-30') mod 30) > 10 then null 
        when (day('2017-01-30') div 30) = 1 then concat(year('2017-01-30'), lpad(month('2017-01-30'), 2, 0)) 
        else concat(year('2017-01-30' - interval 1 month), lpad(month('22017-01-30' - interval 1 month), 2, 0)) 
    end
)
```

As a side note: the fixed date range from days 30th to next month's 10th seems strange - did you consider February in your design, having only 28 or 29 days?

**EDIT**: Actually, use date_format instead of concatenating the year and month values, it's simpler and cleaner:

```
select (
    case 
        when (day('2016-01-30') mod 30) > 10 then null 
        when (day('2016-01-30') div 30) = 1 then date_format('2016-01-30', '%Y%m') 
        else date_format(('2016-01-30' - interval 1 month), '%Y%m') 
    end) 
as period;
```